# How to make duration slider in control center? Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I make Media Player. I want to create a duration slider in control center. How can I make it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func controlCenter() {
    let mpPlaysCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
    mpPlaysCenter.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: artistSongForLabel, MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: nameSongForLabel, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: player.duration, MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount: player.currentTime]
}
```